# Interpretation of vector identity in the context of fluid dynamics

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, energy, vectors, continuum-mechanics

I know that 
$(v \cdot\nabla)v = \nabla(\frac{1}2v^2)+\omega \times v $
is just a general vector identity with $v$ substituted for some general vector field and $\omega$ for $\boldsymbol \nabla \times \boldsymbol v$ .
Despite this I was considering the physical meaning of this formula as a decomposition of acceleration into component that affects the velocity magnitude (so kinetic energy as well) - 1st term of RHS and centripetal component that doesn't - 2nd term of RHS. The problem is that the centripetal acceleration is only half of the second term because angular velocity is a half of the curl.

My question is what went wrong? I have no idea where this additional $\frac{1}2\omega\times v$ comes from physically or why such decomposition is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

The centripetal acceleration (CA) is not $\vec \omega \times \vec v$, as it does not contain any spatial deriative.
Furthermore the CA is fundamentally different from the nonlinear term $(\vec v \cdot \vec \nabla) \vec v$. The CA and Coriolis acceleration originate in a frame transformation of the total time derivative of any vector, while the nonlinear term is only the spatial change component of the total time derivative.

Comment: As far as I know, CA is $\vec{\omega}\times\vec{\omega}\times\vec{R}$, where $\vec{R}$ is distance to instant center of rotation and $\vec{\omega}$ is angular velocity. In case of fluid dynamics, angular velocity of an infinitesimal fluid particle can be expressed as $\frac{1}2\nabla\times v$ and to avoid using $\vec{R}$ we can combine it with $\vec{\omega}$ and use $\vec{v}$ instead, so I think that CA could be expressed as $(\frac{1}2\nabla\times\vec{v})\times\vec{v}$.

Comment: @Pawel: And a derivative becomes R magically? As I said in my answer, that's incorrect. CA, vorticity and the covariant derivative are two completely different concepts, and exist independtly of each other. $\frac{d \vec X}{d t} = \frac{\partial \vec X}{\partial t} + (\vec v \cdot \vec \nabla) \vec X$ is true independent of the coordinate system chosen and of $\vec X$. Check the books by Vallis or Holton.